# Client Side validation In MVC with Entity framework

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a form in which i have to validate my user inputs (i.e, textbox and dropdownlist). in this i have used both MVC architecture as well as entity framework.

In this form i have to make a validation that the input in textboxt should not be blank and the dropdownlist should also contain a valid option

the form is generated using razor html syntax

**VIEW**

```
 <form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Label(" Cartidge Number ") <span style="color:red">*</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CartridgeNumber, "", new { @id = "txtNumber"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Brand)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Label(" Brand ") <span style="color:red">*</span>
            </td>
            <td>

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Brand, ViewBag.BrandId as SelectList,"Please Select", new { @id = "ddlBrands" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Brand)

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
```

**Model**

Modelname is CartridgeModel which is generated using entity framework's database first approach

```
    namespace MultiInfoMediaCloudSolution.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class CartridgeModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Cartridge Number: ")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Please Enter Cartridge Number ")]

        public string CartridgeNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Brand: ")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Please Select Brand ")]
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string CartridgeKeywords { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsActive { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }

        public virtual Brand BrandName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
{
                // check if the user has selected to edit the item or not.

                if (userAction == "Edit")
                {
                    var _Printer = (from c in _multiInfoMediaEntities.PrinterModels
                                    where c.PrinterModelNo.Equals(PrinterModelNo)
                                    select c).First();

                    //to store PrinterModelNo
                    string printerNumberTemp = _Printer.PrinterModelNo;
                    TempData["PrinterModelNo"] = printerNumberTemp;
                    TempData["IsActive"] = _Printer.IsActive;

                    TempData["userAction"] = "Edit";
                    return View(_Printer);
                }
                else
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
```

I am using a javaScript to validate my form which is unusually not giving me any result as per my expections,

the javascript is as follow

**JavaScript**

```
//................................Go Function is user for the Validation in all the List........................
function GO() {
    var ddl = document.getElementById("dllFilter");
    var brands = document.getElementById("ddlBrands");

    if (ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text == "Please Select") {
        alert("Please select search field");
    }

    if(brands.innerText == "Please Select")
    {
        alert("Please select brand")
    }

}
//................................

//.......................Clear function is Used for Clearing the textbox Value from all the List........................
function Clear() {
    document.getElementById('txtSearch').value = 'Enter Value';
    //ViewData["Selected"] = "Please Select";
}
//......................................................................................................
```

So, can anyone help me or guide me in solving this problem. ?

Comment: You have already added the `[Required]` attribute and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`. Just use` jquery-validate-unobtrusive.js` and you get client validation out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you require simple client side validation, you can use the "required" attribute 
`<input type="text" required />` 
 or in your case 
`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CartridgeNumber, "", new { @id = "txtNumber", required = "required"})`

As for the dropdown you can use the same required attribute but for it to work the first 'option' child element must have a blank string for value 
 `<option value="">Please select an option</option>`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke

i tried using that but its not reflecting at the time of running the project forms